# App Engine Python runtime doesn't bring same result as local

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a Python standard project on App Engine. It uses `ast` module to convert Python source code to another language's code. I faced the issue which wasn't caused in the local environment (Python 3.7.4 on macOS 10.15.4). The re-deployment had been successful, but the API wouldn't be updated. Creating another project with the same files didn't work properly. I also tried Cloud Shell by uploading the files or `python3 main.py` on local, then these were correct. Does Python runtime on App Engine have some differences?

Details:

Let [py3ca.py](https://github.com/0xCAF2/calcium/blob/master/py3ca.py) read Python source code below as input on the local environment (`$ python3 py3ca.py fizzbuzz.py`).

```py
# fizzbuzz.py
res = []
for i in range(1, 101):
    if (i % 15) == 0:
        res.append('Fizz Buzz ')
    elif (i % 3) == 0:
        res.append('Fizz ')
    elif (i % 5) == 0:
        res.append('Buzz ')
    else:
        res.append(i)
print(res)
```

This produces:

```
[
  [1, [], "#", "0_18"],
  [1, [], "=", ["var", "res"], [[]]],
  [1, [], "for range", "i", [1, 101]],
    [2, [], "ifs"],
      [3, [], "if", ["==", ["%", ["var", "i"], 15], 0]],
        [4, [], "call", null, ["attr", "res", "append"], ["Fizz Buzz "]],
      [3, [], "elif", ["==", ["%", ["var", "i"], 3], 0]],
        [4, [], "call", null, ["attr", "res", "append"], ["Fizz "]],
      [3, [], "elif", ["==", ["%", ["var", "i"], 5], 0]],
        [4, [], "call", null, ["attr", "res", "append"], ["Buzz "]],
      [3, [], "else"],
        [4, [], "call", null, ["attr", "res", "append"], [["var", "i"]]],
  [1, [], "call", null, ["var", "print"], [["var", "res"]]],
  [1, [], "end"]
]
```

However, [Apps Script which sends to the App Engine](https://sites.google.com/site/calciumlanguage/home/interpreter) produces:
[image: Wrong result]

This doesn't match with the local (lines 8, 10, 12).

Comment: What is the integer value here?

Comment: It shows the indent of each command (an inner array). This indent is corresponding to Python's one.

Comment: Is it possible you're mixing tabs and spaces here? What App Engine runtime are you using?

Comment: 4 spaces are accepted as an indent. I select Python standard (not flexible) environment and use python37 (not python38).

Comment: If you run it inline on App Engine rather than via data from the browser, does it behave the same way?

Comment: Yes. It seems that the value of node.orelse[0].col_offset is different between Python3.7 on local and App Engine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61904643/asts-col-offset-is-different-between-local-and-app-engine

Comment: This is due to a difference between 3.7.7 and Python versions prior to that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61916494/328036