# ast's col_offset is different between local and App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My project on App Engine Python3.7 environment tried using `ast` module:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import ast

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def respond():
    code = '''
if True:
    pass
elif True:
    pass
elif False:
    pass
else:
    pass
'''
    module_node = ast.parse(code)
    visitor = MyVisitor()
    visitor.visit(module_node)
    return visitor.result

class MyVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_If(self, node):
        self.result = '{} {} {} {}'.format(
            node.col_offset,
            node.orelse[0].col_offset,
            node.orelse[0].orelse[0].col_offset,
            node.orelse[0].orelse[0].orelse[0].col_offset
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

The result was '0 5 5 4' on local (Python3.7.4 on macOS 10.15.4). However App Engine returned '0 0 0 4'. How can I resolve this? I need `ast` to parse code and generate another representation. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide more information on how you are deploying your code into App Engine? More information as well, from where this values are being called as well, will help understand better why App Engine might not displaying the values correctly.

Comment: The runtime is specified in `python37` in app.yaml. I use Standard Environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this changed between Python 3.7.6 and Python 3.7.7:

```py
import ast
import sys


class MyVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_If(self, node):
        self.result = '{} {} {} {}'.format(
            node.col_offset,
            node.orelse[0].col_offset,
            node.orelse[0].orelse[0].col_offset,
            node.orelse[0].orelse[0].orelse[0].col_offset
        )


code = '''
if True:
    pass
elif True:
    pass
elif False:
    pass
else:
    pass
'''
module_node = ast.parse(code)
visitor = MyVisitor()
visitor.visit(module_node)
print(sys.version)
print(visitor.result)
```

```
$ python3.7.6 test.py
3.7.6 (default, May 20 2020, 09:51:40)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)]
0 5 5 4

$ python3.7.7 test.py
3.7.7 (default, Apr 24 2020, 10:25:06)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)]
0 0 0 4
```

At the time of writing, App Engine's `python37` runtime uses Python 3.7.7 and [is generally upgraded to the latest patch version as it is released](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#python_3_version).

I would expect the behavior of the newer version of Python to be more "correct" here, and in fact this behavior persists through 3.8 and 3.9 as well:

```
$ python3.8 test.py
3.8.2 (default, Apr 22 2020, 21:21:01)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)]
0 0 0 4

$ python3.9 test.py
3.9.0a5 (default, Apr 24 2020, 10:32:31)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)]
0 0 0 4
```